# How to schedule and send email of python generated report automatically in python

Tags: python, windows, email, report, scheduled-tasks

Is there are way to pick the report from specific folder and send email to mentioned recipient on a specific time schedule using python packages and code in windows 10?

I have an idea and want to have some inspirational codes if anyone can help to begin with this project.

Answer (score 1):

Part 1:

script to send mails in python 
you need to access send_email() function in your main python file in which you schedule the script

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

def send_email(mail_body="", subject=""):
    fromaddr = "sender mail address"
    toaddr_list = [
     //recepients address list
    ]
    passwd = "need to create gmail app to get password"
    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = ", ".join(toaddr_list)
    if(subject):
        msg['Subject'] = subject
    else:
        msg['Subject'] = "subject of mail."

    body = mail_body

    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    s.starttls()
    s.login(fromaddr, passwd)
    text = msg.as_string()
    s.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr_list, text)
    s.quit()
```

Part 2:  schedule script in windows 10
   For scheduling script in windows you can refer this:
    https://datatofish.com/python-script-windows-scheduler/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that using different python packages.

```
Read the specific file
Send mail using built-in smtplib module
Time scheduler using schedule library Or you can use cron or celery in windows.
```

Answer (score 0):

Read Automate the boring stuff - Chapter 16.

You will get both Code and ideas of how to implement the same
[Automate the boring stuff](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter16/)